# Ubuntu starts in terminal mode after deleting packages and cannot reach archive.ubuntu.com

Tags: networking, package-management

Hi I tried to update to Ubuntu 20LTS and I could not because of some package problem. I followed the instructions from here (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1876395) and removed obsolete packages. After restarting, Ubuntu booted in terminal mode only. I tried `sudo startx` but it immediately shuts down. I tried `sudo apt update` but I get the error "*Could not resolve archive.ubuntu.com*". I also tried setting `nameserver 8.8.8.8` in /etc/resolv.conf and then updating. Running `ping www.google.com` yields "*Name or service not known*". I am new to Ubuntu and I am afraid I broke some packages and I do not know what to do now please help.

Comment: Not having internet access, it only remains to reinstall.

Comment: Are you using Lubuntu or Ubuntu?  Did you try just disabling/removing any PPAs first, before removing obsolete packages also?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I managed to actually fix it, here is what I did:
Since I did not have any network access in the terminal mode on startup, I tried the following:

1. Reboot
2. After the logo of the PC disappears press ESC
3. Select Advanced boot
4. Boot in any recovery mode
5. Activate networking
6. Check system status.
   This did not yield any success as there was still no network connection. So I checked some askbuntu posts on this and the solution that worked for me was: (still in recovery mode)
7. Start root shell
8. Check networking interfaces with ifconfig. I only saw `lo`, no `eth0`. So checked again with `ifconfig -a` to find the name of my ethernet interface
9. Edit content of `/etc/network/interfaces`. At this point this file only contained something like

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback
```

So i added something like:

```
auto [ethernet-interface-name]
iface [ethernet-interface-name] inet dhcp
```

As explained in some answer here: [askubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/328800/missing-eth0-ethernet-interface-in-ubuntu-cant-connect-to-router)

10. Checking with ping I saw the network connection now worked. A `apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` fixed everything after a reboot.